# Clone from git windows server though openssh

Tags: git, ssh

```
$ git clone ssh://edu243@server ip/G:/GitRepos/Confiapp.git
Cloning into 'Confiapp'...
edu243@server ip's password:
fatal: ''/G:/GitRepos/Confiapp.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The git file exist in G:\GitRepos\Confiapp.git on windows server.

Locally cloning working but cloning in client machine through ssh ( used OpenSSH for windows) failing.

**First time i am trying git in windows 2008 Server, please anyone help .**

Comment: instead of `.../G:/...` have you tried `ssh://edu243@server ip/g/GitRepos/Confiapp.git`?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Thank you but it is also showing fatal: ''/g/GitRepos/Confiapp.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Hosted in Windows server 2008R2, any configuration needed ?

Comment: does it really print doubled single quotes? Could be some misubderstanding between shell and client. Can you enter the interactive shell?

Answer (score 1):

Check first if `ssh -T edu243@server ip` does work.
If it does, check if you have an interactive shell in which you can execute commands like

```
dir G:/GitRepos/Confiapp.git
```

That will make sure the remote folder does exist and is readable.
Make sure there is no typo (like `Configapp.git` instead of `Confiapp.git`)

Answer (score 0):

(***A very wild guess***)

Based on the single quotes, I can assume that it tries to search the path with quotes included, and obviously fails. It could be that the remote sshd server starts cmd instead of bash. And client sends single-auoted path which cmd does not understand.

You should make sure your sshd starts bash as a shell, or the restricted `git-shell` included with git. That should fix the error.

Comment: thanks, i think the same problem. but please can elaborate the fix like detail , i am very new to this. please.

Comment: I don't know much about setting up sshd at Windows. I do not even dare to drop random advises from Google because I believe there are multiple ways to install and enable it, and each of them may need different way to configure the details.